What is the process for creating a partial index for an email field when email field is not present or as empty field in MongoDB?
I'm using MongoDB and want to create a partial index on the email field, but I only want it to apply to documents where the email field exists (i.e., email: { $exists: true }). How can I create this partial index?
Here is what I have so far:
db.collection.createIndex(
  { email: 1 },
  { partialFilterExpression: { email: { $exists: true } } }
);

When I use this index I don't add a new user without an email or an empty field
Required:
when I add an empty email or null or without email field then it should created many times but I received the error of duplication when I don't want to add an email with a partial Index
Thanks in advance for your help!

It is confusing about what you are trying to do. You try to manage the set of documents that has the email field with a partial index, but at the same time you want to use the same partial index to manage the (complementary) set of documents without the email field???

Maybe you just want to use schema validation?

Not clear what you want to do. You ask "how to create a partial index?". Your code is exactly doing this and works fine - so what is your question? What do you mean by "When I use this index" and "I don't want to add an email with a partial Index"?

I'm here to clarify that when I add a user with no email or email field with an empty string it throws an error of duplication how I handled it is that when the email is the null or empty string (' ')
it does not throw key duplication error

Have a careful at all your indexes. The index you listed here certainly does not throw a key duplication error. Most likely you have created other indexes. Unlike most relational databases an empty field does create an entry in the index in MongoDB.
